# Why I can't get the instant/real-time current offset in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I use  `kafka-consumer-groups --describe --group test --bootstrap-server device2:9092`
to display the latest `CURRENT-OFFSET` while I'm consuming the message (about 10 messages/second).

The output looks like this:

```
TOPIC      PARTITION   CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG         CONSUMER-ID                                             HOST            CLIENT-ID
comment      0          77042           77065           23           kafka-python-1.4.7 
comment      1          77190           77206           16           kafka-python-1.4.7 
comment      2          76677           76682           5            kafka-python-1.4.7
```

And I keep running the above command to print the current offset while it's consuming.

However, what I found was the number of `CURRENT-OFFSET` wasn't refreshed as it should be.
Instead, the number refresh in batch, like from 77042 -> 77142,  100 per batch.

My question is how can I know the real live `CURRENT-OFFSET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to track that offset value from the consumer.

The number you see is indeed the current offset for the moment that API request was made

If you have batchy behavior, that would indicate your consumer is polling batches of messages and you're committing every N messages, for example

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use kafka-python as the consumer. after checking the doc, 
 I found a param called `auto_commit_every_n` inside, which is probably relevant.

Comment: You may want to turn that off if you want different processing semantics such as at least once